# how to optimize too many if else in java android studio?

Tags: java, android, if-statement, optimization

my code is here, how to optimize it?

```
switch (buttonString) {
                case "AC":
                    clearMethod();
                    break;
                case "⌫":
                    deleteMethod();
                    break;
                case "=":
                    equalsMethod();
                    break;
                case "( )":
                    if (mInputText.length() == 0) {
                        updateInputView(mCursorPosition + 1, mCursorPosition,
                                getResources().getString(R.string.bracketleft));
                        mBracketStatus++;
                    } else {
                        String NOT_BEFORE_BRACKET_LEFT = ".anotcsilg";
                        String NOT_AFTER_BRACKET_LEFT = ".+^÷×!%anoig";
                        if (mCursorPosition == mInputText.length()) {
                            if (mBracketStatus > 0) {
                                if (NOT_BEFORE_BRACKET_RIGHT.indexOf(mInputText.charAt(mCursorPosition - 1)) == -1) {
                                    updateInputView(mCursorPosition + 1, mCursorPosition,
                                            getResources().getString(R.string.bracketright));
                                    mBracketStatus--;
                                    updateResultView();
                                } else if (NOT_BEFORE_BRACKET_LEFT.indexOf(mInputText.charAt(mCursorPosition - 1)) == -1) {
                                    updateInputView(mCursorPosition + 1, mCursorPosition,
                                            getResources().getString(R.string.bracketleft));
                                    mBracketStatus++;
                                }
                            } else {
                                if(NOT_BEFORE_BRACKET_LEFT.indexOf(mInputText.charAt(mCursorPosition - 1)) == -1) {
                                    updateInputView(mCursorPosition + 1, mCursorPosition,
                                            getResources().getString(R.string.bracketleft));
                                    mBracketStatus++;
                                }
                            }

                        } else if (mCursorPosition == 0) {
                            if (NOT_AFTER_BRACKET_LEFT.indexOf(mInputText.charAt(0)) == -1) {
                                updateInputView(mCursorPosition + 1, mCursorPosition,
                                        getResources().getString(R.string.bracketleft));
                                mBracketStatus++;
                            }
                        } else {
                            int countBracket = 0;
                            for (int i = 0; i < mCursorPosition + 1; i++) {
                                if (mInputText.charAt(i) == '(') countBracket++;
                                if (mInputText.charAt(i) == ')') countBracket--;
                            }
                            if (countBracket > 0) {
                                String NOT_AFTER_BRACKET_RIGHT = ".anoig";
                                if (NOT_BEFORE_BRACKET_RIGHT.indexOf(mInputText.charAt(mCursorPosition - 1)) == -1
                                        && NOT_AFTER_BRACKET_RIGHT.indexOf(mInputText.charAt(mCursorPosition)) == -1) {
                                    updateInputView(mCursorPosition + 1, mCursorPosition,
                                            getResources().getString(R.string.bracketright));
                                    mBracketStatus--;
                                } else if (NOT_BEFORE_BRACKET_LEFT.indexOf(mInputText.charAt(mCursorPosition - 1)) == -1
                                        && NOT_AFTER_BRACKET_LEFT.indexOf(mInputText.charAt(mCursorPosition)) == -1) {
                                    updateInputView(mCursorPosition + 1, mCursorPosition,
                                            getResources().getString(R.string.bracketleft));
                                    mBracketStatus++;
                                }
                            } else {
                                if (NOT_BEFORE_BRACKET_LEFT.indexOf(mInputText.charAt(mCursorPosition - 1)) == -1
                                        && NOT_AFTER_BRACKET_LEFT.indexOf(mInputText.charAt(mCursorPosition)) == -1) {
                                    updateInputView(mCursorPosition + 1, mCursorPosition,
                                            getResources().getString(R.string.bracketleft));
                                    mBracketStatus++;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case "√":
                    if (mInputText.length() == 0) {
                        updateInputView(mCursorPosition + 1, mCursorPosition, buttonString);
                    } else {
                        if (mCursorPosition == mInputText.length()) {
                            if (mInputText.charAt(mCursorPosition - 1) != '.') {
                                updateInputView(mCursorPosition + 1, mCursorPosition, buttonString);
                            }
                        } else if (mCursorPosition == 0) {
                            if (NOT_AFTER_OPERATOR_1.indexOf(mInputText.charAt(0)) == -1) {
                                updateInputView(mCursorPosition + 1, mCursorPosition, buttonString);
                            }
                        } else {
                            if (mInputText.charAt(mCursorPosition - 1) != '.'
                                    && NOT_AFTER_OPERATOR_1.indexOf(mInputText.charAt(mCursorPosition)) == -1) {
                                updateInputView(mCursorPosition + 1, mCursorPosition, buttonString);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case "log":
                    if (mInputText.length() == 0) {
                        updateInputView(mCursorPosition + 4, mCursorPosition,
                                buttonString + getResources().getString(R.string.bracketleft));
                        mBracketStatus++;
                    } else {
                        if (mCursorPosition == mInputText.length()) {
                            if (mInputText.charAt(mCursorPosition - 1) != '.') {
                                updateInputView(mCursorPosition + 4, mCursorPosition,
                                        buttonString + getResources().getString(R.string.bracketleft));
                                mBracketStatus++;
                            }
                        } else if (mCursorPosition == 0) {
                            if (NOT_AFTER_OPERATOR_1.indexOf(mInputText.charAt(0)) == -1) {
                                updateInputView(mCursorPosition + 4, mCursorPosition,
                                        buttonString + getResources().getString(R.string.bracketleft));
                                mBracketStatus++;
                            }
                        } else {
                            if (mInputText.charAt(mCursorPosition - 1) != '.'
                                    && NOT_AFTER_OPERATOR_1.indexOf(mInputText.charAt(mCursorPosition)) == -1) {
                                updateInputView(mCursorPosition + 4, mCursorPosition,
                                        buttonString + getResources().getString(R.string.bracketleft));
                                mBracketStatus++;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case "tan":
                case "cos":
                case "sin":
                    if (mInputText.length() == 0) {
                        updateInputView(mCursorPosition + 4, mCursorPosition,
                                buttonString + getResources().getString(R.string.bracketleft));
                        mBracketStatus++;
                    } else {
                        if (mCursorPosition == mInputText.length()) {
                            if (mInputText.charAt(mCursorPosition - 1) != '.') {
                                updateInputView(mCursorPosition + 4, mCursorPosition,
                                        buttonString + getResources().getString(R.string.bracketleft));
                                mBracketStatus++;
                            }
                        } else if (mCursorPosition == 0) {
                            if (NOT_AFTER_OPERATOR_2.indexOf(mInputText.charAt(0)) == -1) {
                                updateInputView(mCursorPosition + 4, mCursorPosition,
                                        buttonString + getResources().getString(R.string.bracketleft));
                                mBracketStatus++;
                            }
                        } else {
                            if (mInputText.charAt(mCursorPosition - 1) != '.'
                                    && NOT_AFTER_OPERATOR_2.indexOf(mInputText.charAt(mCursorPosition)) == -1) {
                                updateInputView(mCursorPosition + 4, mCursorPosition,
                                        buttonString + getResources().getString(R.string.bracketleft));
                                mBracketStatus++;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case "%":
                case "!":
                    if (mInputText.length() != 0 && mCursorPosition != 0) {
                        if (mCursorPosition == mInputText.length()) {
                            if (NOT_BEFORE_OPERATOR.indexOf(mInputText.charAt(mCursorPosition - 1)) == -1) {
                                updateInputView(mCursorPosition + 1, mCursorPosition, buttonString);
                            }
                        } else {
                            if (NOT_BEFORE_OPERATOR.indexOf(mInputText.charAt(mCursorPosition - 1)) == -1
                                    && mInputText.charAt(mCursorPosition) != '.') {
                                updateInputView(mCursorPosition + 1, mCursorPosition, buttonString);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    updateResultView();
                    break;
                case "^":
                    if (mInputText.length() != 0 && mCursorPosition != 0) {
                        if (mCursorPosition == mInputText.length()) {
                            if (NOT_BEFORE_OPERATOR.indexOf(mInputText.charAt(mCursorPosition - 1)) == -1) {
                                updateInputView(mCursorPosition + 1, mCursorPosition, buttonString);
                            }
                        } else {
                            if (NOT_BEFORE_OPERATOR.indexOf(mInputText.charAt(mCursorPosition - 1)) == -1
                                    && NOT_AFTER_OPERATOR_2.indexOf(mInputText.charAt(mCursorPosition)) == -1) {
                                updateInputView(mCursorPosition + 1, mCursorPosition, buttonString);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case "-":
                    if (mInputText.length() == 0) {
                        updateInputView(mCursorPosition + 1, mCursorPosition, buttonString);
                    } else {
                        if (mCursorPosition == mInputText.length()) {
                            if (NOT_BEFORE_OPERATOR.indexOf(mInputText.charAt(mCursorPosition - 1)) == -1) {
                                updateInputView(mCursorPosition + 1, mCursorPosition, buttonString);
                            }
                        } else if (mCursorPosition == 0) {
                            if (NOT_AFTER_OPERATOR_1.indexOf(mInputText.charAt(0)) == -1) {
                                updateInputView(mCursorPosition + 1, mCursorPosition, buttonString);
                            }
                        } else {
                            if (NOT_BEFORE_OPERATOR.indexOf(mInputText.charAt(mCursorPosition - 1)) == -1
                                    && NOT_AFTER_OPERATOR_1.indexOf(mInputText.charAt(mCursorPosition)) == -1) {
                                updateInputView(mCursorPosition + 1, mCursorPosition, buttonString);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case "+":
                case "×":
                case "÷":
                    if (mInputText.length() != 0 && mCursorPosition != 0) {
                        if (mCursorPosition == mInputText.length()) {
                            if (NOT_BEFORE_OPERATOR.indexOf(mInputText.charAt(mCursorPosition - 1)) == -1) {
                                updateInputView(mCursorPosition + 1, mCursorPosition, buttonString);
                            }
                        } else {
                            if (NOT_BEFORE_OPERATOR.indexOf(mInputText.charAt(mCursorPosition - 1)) == -1
                                    && NOT_AFTER_OPERATOR_1.indexOf(mInputText.charAt(mCursorPosition)) == -1) {
                                updateInputView(mCursorPosition + 1, mCursorPosition, buttonString);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case "π":
                    if (mInputText.length() == 0) {
                        updateInputView(mCursorPosition + 1, mCursorPosition, buttonString);
                    } else {
                        if (mCursorPosition == mInputText.length()) {
                            if (mInputText.charAt(mCursorPosition - 1) != '.') {
                                updateInputView(mCursorPosition + 1, mCursorPosition, buttonString);
                            }
                        } else if (mCursorPosition == 0) {
                            if (mInputText.charAt(0) != '.' && mInputText.charAt(0) != '!') {
                                updateInputView(mCursorPosition + 1, mCursorPosition, buttonString);
                            }
                        } else {
                            if (mInputText.charAt(mCursorPosition - 1) != '.' && mInputText.charAt(mCursorPosition) != '.'
                                    && mInputText.charAt(mCursorPosition) != '!') {
                                updateInputView(mCursorPosition + 1, mCursorPosition, buttonString);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    updateResultView();
                    break;
                case ".":
                    if (mInputText.length() != 0 && mCursorPosition != 0) {
                        int indexFirst = 0;
                        int indexSecond = mInputText.length() - 1;
                        if (mCursorPosition == mInputText.length()) {
                            for (int i = mCursorPosition - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                                if (NUMBER_NO_POINT.indexOf(mInputText.charAt(i)) == -1) {
                                    indexFirst = i;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                            if (indexFirst == 0) {
                                if (mInputText.charAt(indexFirst) != '.') {
                                    updateInputView(mCursorPosition + 1, mCursorPosition, buttonString);
                                    updateResultView();
                                }
                            } else {
                                if (mInputText.charAt(indexFirst) != '.' && indexFirst != mCursorPosition - 1) {
                                    updateInputView(mCursorPosition + 1, mCursorPosition, buttonString);
                                    updateResultView();
                                }
                            }

                        } else {
                            for (int i = mCursorPosition - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                                if (NUMBER_NO_POINT.indexOf(mInputText.charAt(i)) == -1) {
                                    indexFirst = i;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                            for (int i = mCursorPosition; i < mInputText.length(); i++) {
                                if (NUMBER_NO_POINT.indexOf(mInputText.charAt(i)) == -1) {
                                    indexSecond = i;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                            if (indexFirst == 0 && indexSecond == mInputText.length() - 1) {
                                if (mInputText.charAt(indexFirst) != '.' && mInputText.charAt(indexSecond) != '.') {
                                    updateInputView(mCursorPosition + 1, mCursorPosition, buttonString);
                                    updateResultView();
                                }
                            } else if (indexFirst == 0 && indexSecond != mInputText.length() - 1) {
                                if (mInputText.charAt(indexFirst) != '.' && mInputText.charAt(indexSecond) != '.'
                                        && indexSecond != mCursorPosition) {
                                    updateInputView(mCursorPosition + 1, mCursorPosition, buttonString);
                                    updateResultView();
                                }
                            } else if (indexFirst != 0 && indexSecond == mInputText.length() - 1
                                    && indexFirst != mCursorPosition - 1) {
                                if (mInputText.charAt(indexFirst) != '.' && mInputText.charAt(indexSecond) != '.') {
                                    updateInputView(mCursorPosition + 1, mCursorPosition, buttonString);
                                    updateResultView();
                                }
                            } else {
                                if (mInputText.charAt(indexFirst) != '.' && mInputText.charAt(indexSecond) != '.'
                                        && indexFirst != mCursorPosition - 1 && indexSecond != mCursorPosition) {
                                    updateInputView(mCursorPosition + 1, mCursorPosition, buttonString);
                                    updateResultView();
                                }
                            }

                        }
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    if (mInputText.length() == 0) {
                        updateInputView(mCursorPosition + 1, mCursorPosition, buttonString);
                    } else {
                        if (mInputText.length() == 1) {
                            if (mInputText.charAt(0) == '0') {
                                mInputText = new StringBuilder(buttonString);
                                mInputView.setText(mInputText);
                                mInputView.setSelection(mCursorPosition + 1);
                            } else {
                                updateInputView(mCursorPosition + 1, mCursorPosition, buttonString);
                            }
                        } else {
                            updateInputView(mCursorPosition + 1, mCursorPosition, buttonString);
                        }
                    }
                    updateResultView();
            }
```

i just know that i can replace if else with switch in some case but i think my code need more optimization.

Comment: Please be specific, what optimization are you looking for and why?

Comment: Well the first thing to do is break each of those case statements into their own function.  handleDot, handleDivide, handleMultiply, etc.

Comment: Looks like you need to write a proper scanner or parser for these input strings, and separate it from this UI code.

Answer (score 0):

To optimize the given Java code, you can consider the following improvements:

1. Extract repeated code segments: Some parts of the code are repeated multiple times, such as input validation conditions. You can extract these conditions into separate methods to avoid redundancy and improve code readability.
2. Use constants or variables for repeated string values: Strings like "buttonString" and various resource strings are used multiple times. It's better to assign them to constants or variables at the beginning of the code to improve code readability and maintainability.
3. Reduce nested if-else statements: The code contains nested if-else statements, which can make the code harder to read and understand. You can refactor the conditions to reduce the nesting by using early returns or extracting condition checks into separate methods.
4. Simplify complex conditions: Some conditions in the code are long and complex, making them harder to comprehend. Break down complex conditions into smaller, more manageable parts and use meaningful variable names to improve code readability.

Here's an optimized version of the code with the mentioned improvements:

```
code in java

// Constants
private static final String BUTTON_AC = "AC";
private static final String BUTTON_DELETE = "⌫";
private static final String BUTTON_EQUALS = "=";
private static final String BUTTON_BRACKET = "( )";
private static final String BUTTON_SQRT = "√";
private static final String BUTTON_LOG = "log";
private static final String BUTTON_TAN = "tan";
private static final String BUTTON_COS = "cos";
private static final String BUTTON_SIN = "sin";
private static final String BUTTON_PERCENT = "%";
private static final String BUTTON_FACTORIAL = "!";
private static final String BUTTON_POWER = "^";
private static final String BUTTON_MINUS = "-";
private static final String BUTTON_PLUS = "+";
private static final String BUTTON_MULTIPLY = "×";
private static final String BUTTON_DIVIDE = "÷";
private static final String BUTTON_PI = "π";
private static final String BUTTON_DOT = ".";

// Helper method to check if a character is a digit
private boolean isDigit(char c) {
    return Character.isDigit(c);
}

// Helper method to check if a character is a number without a decimal point
private boolean isNumberNoPoint(char c) {
    return isDigit(c) && c != '.';
}

// Helper method to check if a character is an operator
private boolean isOperator(char c) {
    return c == '+' || c == '-' || c == '×' || c == '÷' || c == '^';
}

// Helper method to check if a character is a valid before-operator character
private boolean isNotBeforeOperator(char c) {
    return isDigit(c) || c == ')' || c == '!';
}

// Helper method to check if a character is a valid after-operator character for operators like √, log, tan, cos, sin
private boolean isNotAfterOperator1(char c) {
    return isDigit(c) || c == '.';
}

// Helper method to check if a character is a valid after-operator character for operators like tan, cos, sin
private boolean isNotAfterOperator2(char c) {
    return isDigit(c) || c == '.';
}

// Helper method to update input view
private void updateInputView(int start, int end, String text) {
    // Implementation of updateInputView method
}

// Helper method to update result view
private void updateResultView() {
    // Implementation of updateResultView method
}

// Main method
public void processButton(String buttonString) {
    String mInputText = getInputText(); // Get the input text
    int mCursorPosition = getCursorPosition(); // Get the cursor position
    int mBracketStatus = getBracketStatus(); // Get the bracket status
```

then use switch